# Viddler API Getting all the videos of a certain user

Tags: php, javascript, api

I'm integrating http://www.viddler.com in my website.

I keep on searching on their [API](http://developers.viddler.com/) how to get all videos of a certain user. The problem is I really can't find it and I know it is possible to get all the videos of a certain users.
Kindly teach me or show me how to do it.

Thanks. Your help would be greatly rewarded and appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.viddler.com/documentation/api-v2/#toc-viddler-videos-getbyuser

```
  Parameters
page - integer - optional
per_page - integer - optional
user - string - required
status - boolean - optional
sort - string - optional. Allowed values: "uploaded-desc", "uploaded-asc", "views-desc", "views-asc". Defaults to "uploaded-desc"
tags - comma delimited list of tags - optional
```